# SQLite Query Duplicate record

Tags: sqlite

I created two tables having following records.

```
CREATE TABLE ForgeRock
    (`id` int,`sta` int, `productName` varchar(7), `description` varchar(55));

INSERT INTO ForgeRock
    (`id`,`sta`, `productName`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 0,'OpenIDM', 'Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions'),

(2,0, 'OpenAM', 'Full-featured access management'),
(3,0, 'OpenDJ', 'Robust LDAP server for Java');


CREATE TABLE ForgeRock1
(`id` int,`sta` int, `productName` varchar(7), `description` varchar(55));

INSERT INTO ForgeRock1
(`id`,`sta`, `productName`, `description`)
```

VALUES

```
(1, 2,'hii', 'Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions'),
(2,0, 'OpenAM', 'Full-featured access management'),
(3,0, 'OpenDJ', 'Robust LDAP server for Java');
```

I want to Union both tables but want records of duplicate id having sta=2

```
SELECT id,sta
    FROM ForgeRock
    GROUP BY id
    UNION 
   SELECT id, sta 
    FROM ForgeRock1
    GROUP BY id
```

Result:

`id  sta
 1   0
 2   0
 3   0
 1   2`

Expected Result:

`id  sta
 1   2
 2   0
 3   0`

Answer (score 0):

Do the grouping *after* the UNION, and use MAX() to select the row to output for each group:

```
SELECT id, MAX(sta) AS sta
FROM (SELECT id, sta
      FROM ForgeRock
      UNION
      SELECT id, sta
      FROM ForgeRock1)
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```